# How to get current year in dotCMS?

Tags: dotcms

How to get current year in dotCMS? I need to display it in footer copyright. I am try this `$date.format('YYYY', $UtilMethods.getCurrentDate())` but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$dateString = $date.format('yyyy',$UtilMethods.getCurrentDate())
```

Not sure entirely, looks right, maybe try lower case 'yyyy' is the only difference I found in research.

Answer (score 0):

This will give the result 2012: $date.format('yyyy',$UtilMethods.getCurrentDate())

Here you can find alot more about dotCMS and Velocity http://dotcms.org/documentation/VelocityAndDotCMS